# Is it normal to use place to represent a group of people?

Tags: grammar

Consider this example:

> After **the police office** collects all the evidences, they arrest him.

Is it correct to use *the police **office*** instead of *the police **office's staff*** in the sentence above?

If it is, should I add '-s' at the end of the verb?

Comment: As an aside… the noun "evidence" is collective and uncountable, rather than discrete and countable; therefore the correct usage is "all the evidence". =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an example of [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) and it is very common. It's particularly noticeable with prominent public institutions (like "The White House" and "The Kremlin") but it's just as common with smaller institutions: "The hospital let me go home".

As for whether to use a singular ("collects") or a plural ("collect") verb, there are differing views. In American English, the authorities insist on a singular verb when the subject is formally singular; but British usage is more flexible, and both singular and plural verbs are acceptable with collective subjects.

Comment: what about possession, should we use "its" or "their"?

Comment: ^ re: possession — handled the same way as whether to use a singular or plural verb.

Comment: Incidentally, in British usage we don't say "Police Office": it is understandable, but marks you as a foreigner. We usuall refer to the building as the _Police Station_; but in a context like this, unless there was some reason to single out the particular police station, we would just say "After the police collect all the evidence... "

Comment: "Police office" isn't used in American English either.  "The police" or "the officers" arrested whomever.